# I'm getting uninitialized constant FayeOnline_Rails::Engine::QA_Rails (NameError) error. What that mean?

Tags: rubygems, faye

I want to make simple chat with private and public channels (with Faye). I'm using gem 'thin' and gem 'faye' and I don't use gem 'private-pub'. Of course, I need online users list. I made decision to use gem 'faye-online'. As mentioned in instruction (https://github.com/eoecn/faye-online) I added this gem to Gemfile and performed

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

After running this command i got this error:

```
uninitialized constant FayeOnline_Rails::Engine::QA_Rails (NameError)
```

Can someone explain what this mistake means and how should I solve this issue?